# How to correctly dispose SpeechToText in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition

So, in my Flutter project I have two routes, the second one uses the [SpeechToText](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text/) package. When I go from the first to the second route for the first time everything works fine but when I go back and go to the second one again the `onStatus` method is not called when it should be.

I did a little debugging and here is what I found: The `onStatus` method is set in the `SpeechToText().initialize` method. It initializes the methods if the variable `_initWorked` false. But when I open the route the second time the variable is already set to `true` even though I have a completely different instance of `SpeechToText`.

This leads me to think that it is still activated on an OS-level. But I just cannot find a way to entirely dispose it. Is there a way to do so, is it a bug in the package itself or is it because of something completely different?

**Any help would be highly appreciated :)**

Answer (score 0):

`SpeechToText` is a `Singleton`, you always get the same instance 
 https://github.com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/blob/1a0864910db88eb83cdde113b447baa7405eaa7e/speech_to_text/lib/speech_to_text.dart#L89 
source code snippet

```
class SpeechToText {
   ...
   static final SpeechToText _instance = SpeechToText.withMethodChannel(); 
   ...
   factory SpeechToText() => _instance;
```

To dispose `SpeechToText` you can call `stop()`
it will cal `destroyRecognizer()` and do `speechRecognizer?.destroy();` `speechRecognizer = null;` 
https://github.com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/blob/1a0864910db88eb83cdde113b447baa7405eaa7e/speech_to_text/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt#L511 
Android source code snippet

```
public class SpeechToTextPlugin : ...
    ...
    private var speechRecognizer: SpeechRecognizer? = null
    ...
    "stop" -> stopListening(result)     
    ...
    private fun stopListening(result: Result) {
            if (sdkVersionTooLow() || isNotInitialized() || isNotListening()) {
                result.success(false)
                return
            }
            debugLog("Stop listening")
            handler.post {
                run {
                    speechRecognizer?.stopListening()
                }
            }
            if ( !recognizerStops ) {
                destroyRecognizer()
            }
            notifyListening(isRecording = false)
            result.success(true)
            debugLog("Stop listening done")
        }       
    ...
    private fun destroyRecognizer() {

        handler.postDelayed( {
                run {
                    debugLog("Recognizer destroy")
                    speechRecognizer?.destroy();
                    speechRecognizer = null;
                }
        }, 50 )
    }
```

Comment: I tried calling await _speech.stop(); but it doesn't seem to work. Afterwards the instance of SpeechToText still exists...

Comment: @Stefan, I suggest post your issue to github to allow owner check it.